# Concanate data from one table to another

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to concanate the data from TABLE1 to TABLE 2

TABLE 1

```
id        grp_name
-----------------------------
1       A@erf,R@erf.in
2       B@go.in,D@st.org/S@rec.uy
3       C@st.org,X@we.in,S@erl.in
4       D@gh.ou#F@rt.ot
5       E@rth.or
```

TABLE 2

```
code       name
-----------------------------------
1        A@we.ot,D@ref.as
2        B@de.in
3        C@gr.cpm
4        D@yahoo.com
5        E@erf.com
6        F@google.com
```

I want to join grp_name data with name data like concanate using comma (',')
grp_name data having unwanted symboles like '#', '/', I want to elimate those too.

I created below procedure, but i dont know i effective or not.
If it is possible with simple update statement alone or merge statement alone let me know.

Excepted result

```
code       name
1        A@we.ot,D@ref.as,A@erf,R@erf.in
2        B@de.in,B@go.in,D@st.org,S@rec.uy
3        C@gr.cpm,C@st.org,X@we.in,S@erl.in
4        D@yahoo.com,D@gh.ou,F@rt.ot
5        E@erf.com,E@rth.or
6        F@google.com
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure1
AS

    CURSOR cur
    IS
    SELECT id, grp_name
    FROM TABLE 1;
    
    CURSOR cur2
    IS
    SELECT code, name
    FROM TABLE 2;
    
      v_a       VARCHAR2(300);
 v_b       VARCHAR2(25);
 v_c    VARCHAR2(4000);
 v_d       VARCHAR2(250);

BEGIN

    FOR i IN cur
    LOOP
        v_a := ','||i.grp_name;
        v_b := i.id;
        
        FOR e IN cur2
        LOOP
            v_c := e.name || v_a ;
            v_d := i.code;
        
    
        UPDATE schema_name.TABLE 2
        SET name = v_c
        WHERE v_d = v_b;
        
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    
--  COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: With that table data, what is the expected result?

Comment: @jarlh Please check now, am edited by excepted result.

Comment: First UPDATE matching id's. Then INSERT non-matching ids (none in your sample data, you should have id 7 in table1.)

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a string column, particularly in a database such as Oracle that has many alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest case, like @jarlh said, you can just do an update:

```
update table2
    set name = name 
            || (select ',' || regexp_replace(grp_name, '[/#]', ',') -- replace / and # with ,
                from table1
                where table1.id = table2.code)
where code in (select id from table1); -- only update matching rows
```

The last line is not strictly necessary, but it's good to avoid unnecessary updates.

If you also have rows in TABLE1 which don't have a match in TABLE2 that you want to add, use an insert:

```
insert into table2 (code, name)
    select id, regexp_replace(grp_name, '[/#]', ',')
    from table1
    where id not in (select code from table2);
```

Edit: and like Gordon mentioned, you would have an easier time with the SQL if you stored your data like this:

```
code       name
1        A@we.ot
1        D@ref.as
1        A@erf
1        R@erf.in
2        B@de.in
2        B@go.in
2        D@st.org
2        S@rec.uy
3        C@gr.cpm
3        C@st.org
3        X@we.in
3        S@erl.in
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like this:

```
With tab1 as
(
select 1 as id,'A@er#f,R@erf.in' as grp_name from dual union all
select 2 as id,'B@go.in,D@st.or#g/S@rec.uy' as grp_name from dual
),
tab2 as (
select 1 as id,'A@we.ot,D@ref.as' as name from dual union all
select 2 as id,'B@de.in' as name from dual
)
select REGEXP_REPLACE (grp_name||','||name,'[^a-zA-Z0-9|\@|\,]','') as name from tab1 inner join tab2 using(id);
```

Result:

```
A@erf,R@erfin,A@weot,D@refas
B@goin,D@storgS@recuy,B@dein
```